# CSS - Trouble aligning text elements on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a footer bar which has a text element aligned on the left and one thats aligned to the right, however I'm having some difficulty.

This is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer_bar">
    <div id="footer_bar_content">
        <p>
            Left Text
        </p>

        <p class="align_right">
            Right Text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer_bar
{ 
    width:100%;
    position:absolute; 
    margin:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    height:30px; 
    border-top:2px #eeeeee solid; 
    background-color:#f7f7f7; 
}

#footer_bar_content     { padding-left:15%; padding-right:15%; }
#footer_bar_content p   { line-height:30px; margin:0; color:#222; font-size:11px; display:inline; }

.align_right    { text-align:right; width:100%; }
```

Please could someone help me work out what is wrong? The align_right class doesn't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for.  Take a look at `fiddle`. http://jsfiddle.net/GD8tL/1/

Use `float` instead of `align`

```
#footer_bar
{ 
    width:100%;
    position:absolute; 
    margin:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    height:30px; 
    border-top:2px #eeeeee solid; 
    background-color:#f7f7f7; 
}

#footer_bar_content     { padding-left:15%; padding-right:15%; }
#footer_bar_content p   { line-height:30px; margin:0; color:#222; font-size:11px; display:inline; }

.align_right{ float:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try float `right` or `left` accordingly,

### Html

```
<div id="footer_bar">
    <div id="footer_bar_content">
        <p class="left">
            Left Text
        </p>

        <p class="right">
            Right Text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### StyleSheet

```
#footer_bar
{ 
    width:100%;
    position:absolute; 
    margin:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    height:30px; 
    border-top:2px #eeeeee solid; 
    background-color:#f7f7f7; 
}

#footer_bar_content { padding: 0 15%; }
#footer_bar_content p { line-height:30px; margin:0; color:#222; font-size:11px; display:inline; }
.right { float:right; }
.left { float:left; }
```

Here is the <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2WMSk/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however using float right seems to cause the right hand text to drop onto a new line. I need them to be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer_bar_content p.align_right {float:right; width:100%;}
```

Try this if you want your text on the right side, and play a bit with the width, because you want to give 100% of the main div's width, which is the whole place, so probably it will be displayed in new line.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove width = 100% in class align_right and use "float: right" instead of "text-align:right"

CSS:

```
.align_right    { float:right;}
```

Code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/blck/6Un7J/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="footer_bar">
    <div id="footer_bar_content">
        <p>
            Left Text


        <span style="float: right;">
            Right Text
        </span>
        </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of paragraph you should take

left.. similar for right and use .left{float:left} and .right{float:right} then .footer_bar_content:after{clear:both} will work for u